# Java Spring Boot - Not able to remove fields from database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 4 tables in my database

[image]

Despite type of question it can have options or not.

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Presentation updatePresentation(Long id, PresentationRequestDto updatedPresentationRequest,
            UserPrincipal currentUser) {
        Presentation presentation = presentationRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(AppConstants.PRESENTATION, AppConstants.ID, id));
        if (AppUtils.checkUserIsCurrentUserOrAdmin(presentation.getUser(), currentUser)) {
            presentation.setTitle(updatedPresentationRequest.getTitle());

            List<Slide> existingSlides = presentation.getSlides();
            List<SlideRequestDto> updatedSlides = updatedPresentationRequest.getSlides();

            for (SlideRequestDto updatedSlide : updatedSlides) {
                if (updatedSlide.getId() != null) {
                    Slide existingSlide = existingSlides.stream()
                            .filter(slide -> slide.getId().equals(updatedSlide.getId())).findFirst()
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(AppConstants.SLIDE, AppConstants.ID,
                                    updatedSlide.getId()));
                    existingSlide.setTitle(updatedSlide.getTitle());
                    SlideType slideType = slideTypeRepository.findByName(SlideTypeName.valueOf(updatedSlide.getType()));
                    existingSlide.setType(slideType);

                    if (AppConstants.OPTIONS_SLIDES_TYPES.contains(slideType.getName())) {
                        List<Option> existingOptions = existingSlide.getOptions();
                        List<Option> updatedOptions = updatedSlide.getOptions();

                        // update existing option
                        for (Option updatedOption : updatedOptions) {
                            for (Option existingOption : existingOptions) {
                                if (existingOption.getId() != null
                                        && existingOption.getId().equals(updatedOption.getId())) {
                                    existingOption.setOption(updatedOption.getOption());
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // add new option
                        for (Option updatedOption : updatedOptions) {
                            if (updatedOption.getId() == null) {
                                Option newOption = new Option();
                                newOption.setOption(updatedOption.getOption());
                                newOption.setSlide(existingSlide);
                                existingOptions.add(newOption);
                            }
                        }

                        // remove options that are not in updateOptions list
                        existingOptions.removeIf(existingOption -> existingOption.getId() != null
                                && updatedOptions.stream().noneMatch(updatedOption -> updatedOption.getId() != null
                                        && updatedOption.getId().equals(existingOption.getId())));

                    }
                } else {
                    SlideType slideType = slideTypeRepository.findByName(SlideTypeName.valueOf(updatedSlide.getType()));
                    Slide newSlide = new Slide();
                    newSlide.setTitle(updatedSlide.getTitle());
                    newSlide.setType(slideType);
                    newSlide.setPresentation(presentation);
                    if (AppConstants.OPTIONS_SLIDES_TYPES.contains(slideType.getName())) {
                        List<Option> options = new ArrayList<>();
                        Option option = new Option();
                        for (Option updatedOption : updatedSlide.getOptions()) {
                            Option newOption = new Option();
                            newOption.setOption(updatedOption.getOption());
                            newOption.setSlide(newSlide);
                            options.add(option);
                        }
                        newSlide.setOptions(options);
                    }
                    presentation.addSlide(newSlide);
                }
            }

            existingSlides.removeIf(
                    existingSlide -> updatedSlides.stream().noneMatch(updatedSlide -> updatedSlide.getId() != null
                            && updatedSlide.getId().equals(existingSlide.getId())));

            Presentation updatedPresentation = presentationRepository.save(presentation);
            return updatedPresentation;
        }

        throw new UnauthorizedException(new ApiResponseDto(false, "You do not have permissions to edit that post."));

    }
```

I have some presentations already created and I want to update fields on it. I want to increase and decrease number of options and slides. Adding new options/slides to request body works fine. Updating already present option or slide title works too. But when I want to decrease number of options/slides they are still in database and in the response body.

I have presentation like that:

```
{
    "createdAt": "2023-07-20T16:35:52.935813600Z",
    "id": 23,
    "title": "test",
    "code": "810817",
    "slides": [
        {
            "createdAt": "2023-07-20T16:35:52.976128400Z",
            "id": 23,
            "title": "z options",
            "type": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "MULTIPLE_CHOICE"
            },
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "option": "Updated Option 1 for Slide 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "option": "Updated Option 2 for Slide 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "option": "New Option for Slide 1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want to update it using below request body so I want to delete options with ids 11 and 12, and update option name for "new". Updating name works but deleting doen not.

```
{
  "title": "Updated Presentation Title",
  "slides": [
    {
      "id": 23,
      "title": "Updated Slide 1 Title",
      "type": "MULTIPLE_CHOICE",
      "options": [
        {
            "id": 10,
          "option": "new"
        }
      ]
    }]
}
```

My models:
Presentation.java:

```
package com.project.mindsync.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.project.mindsync.model.audit.DateAudit;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "presentatations")
@Setter
@Getter
public class Presentation extends DateAudit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "presentation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Slide> slides;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "presentation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Show> shows;

    public List<Slide> getSlides() {
        return slides == null ? null : new ArrayList<>(slides);
    }

    public void addSlide(Slide slide) {
        if (slides == null) {
            slides = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        slides.add(slide);
        slide.setPresentation(this);
    }

    public void setSlides(List<Slide> slides) {
        this.slides = slides;
    }

    public List<Show> getShows() {
        return shows == null ? null : new ArrayList<>(shows);
    }

    public void setShows(List<Show> shows) {
        if (shows == null) {
            this.shows = null;
        } else {
            this.shows = Collections.unmodifiableList(shows);
        }
    }
}
```

SLide.java:

```
package com.project.mindsync.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.project.mindsync.model.audit.DateAudit;
import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "slides")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Slide extends DateAudit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private SlideType type;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "presentation_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Presentation presentation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "slide", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Option> options;

    public SlideType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Slide(String title, SlideType slideType) {
        this.title = title;
        this.type = slideType;
    }

    public List<Option> getOptions() {
        return options == null ? null : new ArrayList<>(options);
    }

    public void setOptions(List<Option> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public void removeOption(Option option){
        options.remove(option);
        option.setSlide(this);
    }

}
```

I tried to debug code and after this part of code:

```
existingOptions.removeIf(existingOption -> existingOption.getId() != null
                                && updatedOptions.stream().noneMatch(updatedOption -> updatedOption.getId() != null
                                        && updatedOption.getId().equals(existingOption.getId())));
```

options/slides seems to be removed correctly but then database are not being updated